# No code displayed when I open the compiled R notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I am using R Studio V 1.1.423. I create and save R Notebook files but once I open the .rmd files in R Studio I only get a completely blank page with no code displayed.

However the html files work fine when opened in the browser.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in RStudio: It happens every once in a while. It usually helps to delete the R Notebook output (the `.nb.html` file) and to recompile it from scratch.

You might also have to clear the cache, which can be found (on Unix-like systems) in `~/.rstudio-desktop/notebooks`:

1. Close RStudio.
2. Find the subfolder corresponding to your notebook and delete it. The subfolder contains a quasi-random hexadecimal prefix, followed by your notebook name; for instance: `A88D397F-notebook`.
3. Reopen RStudio and recompile your notebook from scratch.